Bitnami Airflow chart 19.0.3 (Airflow version 2.10) not creating pods with unique names

Reason: Conflict
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'd4e76ef2-4512-4e87-a2e6-bb413059a56b', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '6b88bf45-8d78-4ff4-a34b-30a9c78851f7', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '78237e1f-d9d6-49bc-82c1-c2d3a1bb1f1b', 'Date': 'Thu, 29 Aug 2024 10:41:28 GMT', 'Content-Length': '184'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods "rpd" already exists","reason":"AlreadyExists","details":{"name":"rpd","kind":"pods"},"code":409}

I see people reported this issue in the older versions of airflow, but not sure whether it can be fixed with airflow config updates.
I am trying to upgrade my airflow bitnami chart version from 13.1.1 to 19.0.3

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

executor_config = test_akr_dag_utils.executor('test')
dag = DAG(DAG_NAME, default_args=default_args,schedule_interval='@once')
test_cmd = BashOperator(
task_id="test_cmd",
executor_config=executor_config,
bash_command=". $HOME/.bashrc ; set; echo 'the panel value: '; echo $TEST_IMAGE_TAG; echo $SHAW_OFFSET; echo $STB_NGV_TUNES_OUTPUT; sleep 259200",
dag=dag)

container:
test:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: test
spec:
containers:
- name: base
image: test.image
imagePullPolicy: {{ .image.pullPolicy }}
volumeMounts:
- name: test-data
mountPath: /home/akr/batch/data
readOnly: False
envFrom:
- configMapRef:
name: test-config
- configMapRef:
name: test-akr-airflow-env
volumes:
- name: test-data
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: pvc-test-data

by commenting the metadata.name in the executor.yaml, i could now able to get unique pod names. thank you all
